# Finite {2.3}-group with 4 Sylow 3-subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite {$2$,$3$}-group, the number of Sylow $3$-subgroups of $G$ be $4$, and a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G$ be normal in $G$. Let $N$ be the kernel of the conjugation action of $G$ on its Sylow $3$-subgroup. Why $G/N$ is isomorphic to $A_{4}$?

Comment: I know $G/N$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_{4}$. Since $S_{4}$ has $3$ Sylow $2$-subgroup, $G/N$ is not isomorphic to $S_{4}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let P be a Sylow 3-subgroup of G. By Sylow's Theorem, $|G:P|$ is a multiple of 4. On the other hand, $|P:N|=3$, hence $|G/N|\geq 12$. As $G/N$ is a proper subgroup of $S_4$, it must be $A_4$.